# How to remove window wood trim to replace crank operator?

Tags: wood, trim, removal

[image][image: pic3[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRJzH.jpg)[[image: pic 2]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtKVC.jpg)
I have a broken casement window crank operator and needs to replace it, got the parts, but can't figure out a way to put it in. There are wood trims on the window which keeps me from reaching the screws for the operator, as shown in the picture. How should these wood trims be removed, so I can reach the screws to replace the operator? Thanks!

[image: wood trim blocking crank operator]

Comment: Hard to tell from these pix where the screws are.  firstly, I agree with Ecnerwal's suggestion; secondly, depending on what sort of clearance there really is, consider a nut-driver with a flexible cable extension (you put a screwdriver bit on the end of the cable)

Answer (score 5):

### Use a thin prybar, carefully.

Look closely at the joints on the bottom trim piece that's in your way, and you'll note that it's not "locked in" to the rest of the frame - because that piece was installed after the crank hardware was. Pry it out of there, replace the hardware, and tack it back in when done.

Comment: the nails are the hard part to take it out - there are 3 of them, and all hidden under the wood

Answer (score 0):

In my experience they are usually attached with screws so you can remove them for servicing of the mechanism. It is possible that it could be just friction or small finish nails but if not prying it will break it.

In the third photo i can see what appears to be screw threads in a hole.

The heads of the screws that hold the wood cover in place have probably been painted over many times.

Use a [neodymium magnet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KF61YZT) over the top of the wood covering until it finds the screw heads, then mark with a pencil, now you can gently pry out the paint with an awl or a small screwdriver to expose the screw heads.

Comment: it worked after taking out the nails, they are all hidden